# Usando Math.floor para calcular tempo de casa

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá pessoal tudo bem com vcs?? Vejam se podem me ajudar, tenho 3 inputs, um deles coloco a data que o funcionário entrou e no outro a data que o funcionário foi desligado. O 3° input apresenta o tempo de casa, porém está inserindo 4 números zero após o resultado, estou tentando tratar/removelos com Math.floor mas não está funcionando. Conseguem me ajudar?

```js
  $('#desligamento').focusout(function(){
    var x = document.getElementById('admissao').value.replace(/[^\d]+/g,'');
    var y = document.getElementById('desligamento').value.replace(/[^\d]+/g,'');
    var z = Math.floor(document.getElementById('resultado').value = y - x);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" id="admissao" placeholder="Admissao">
<input type="date" id="desligamento" placeholder="Desligamento">
<input type="text" id="resultado" placeholder="Tempo trabalhado" disabled>
```

Comment: Tem certeza? pois executando pelo stackoverflow esta correto

Comment: Então caro Everton, percebeu que o resultado está exorbitante? Preciso remover esse excesso de zeros e deixar só os 2 primeiros números.

Comment: Aqui o resultado está saindo correto. Sem excessos.

Comment: Não quero insistir mas você poderia me enviar o print?

Comment: Uma palpite: quando você diz que o script está inserindo quatro números depois do resultado, você está colocando uma data com uma diferença de um ano e a sua expectativa é obter o resultado em anos. Agora, os colegas que dizem que o resultado está correto, provavelmente estão testando uma diferença de dias e estão esperando o resultado em dias. Bem, se o meu palpite estiver correto, o problema do seu script é uma questão de teste. Você precisa testar com mais valores.